# PHP JSON: print blank page when result is empty

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this Code for fetch data from MySql database using `php` `json` method.

```
$ret  = array();
if(isset($_GET['userid'])){
$user = detect_attakcs($_GET['userid']);
$sql = DataSQL::FETCH("SELECT image FROM news WHERE user = ? ",$user);
foreach($sql as $value){
$ret[] = $value['image'];
}
echo json_encode($ret);
}
```

Output if result not empty:

```
["1.jpg","member_ph.png","user.jpg"]
```

Output when no result (empty)

```
[""]
```

now, i need to print blank page and not print `[""]` when **result** is **empty**.

How do can i fix this ?

Comment: I love the function name `detect_attacks`. I'll have to remember that one.

Comment: Yea, the name is funny. I would like to know what it contains. `$user = inval($_GET['userid']);` would have been enough.

Comment: It might not be misspelled. This is how `attacks` might be in his language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it has become clear that the asker *never* wants to show `[""]` and that entries added to `$ret` may be empty, in which case we do not want to show any JSON, either. Let's check that only data is added to `$ret` that isn't empty. Afterwards, we check whether or not `$ret` is [`empty`](http://ch2.php.net/empty).

```
$ret  = array();
if (isset($_GET['userid'])) {
   $user = detect_attakcs($_GET['userid']);
   $sql = DataSQL::FETCH("SELECT image FROM news WHERE user = ? ",$user);
   foreach ($sql as $value) {
     // Only add values to $ret that contain something other than whitespace
     if (trim($value['image']) != '') {
         $ret[] = $value['image'];
     }
   }
   if (!empty($ret)) {
       echo json_encode($ret);
   }
}
```

---

Alternatively, if we had a lot of complicated conditions in which the output would be `[""]`, we could just check whether or not the output is `[""]` and only output it in the cases when it is not equals to that. This might still output similarly empty values, though.

```
   $json_output = json_encode($ret);
   if ($json_output != '[""]') {
       echo $json_output;
   }
```

Comment: This is not ok. He wants an empty array when there are no results.

Comment: @machineaddict The OP said: "now, i need to print blank page and **not** print `[""]` when result is empty" (emphasis mine)

Comment: @ljacqu: This is false! `if (count($ret) == 0) {echo json_encode($ret);}` The OP said: print blank page **if** result empty **else** print result.

Comment: @ღ..Sambora..ღ: you right. this code not work for me

Comment: @ljacqu: not work. i think count not work with $ret `array`. can u test your code?

Comment: @user27133 What's the error? It works for me. If it's because of `detect_attakcs` (sic), note that this is how it is in your post – it may have to be `detect_attacks`. Otherwise, I would be thankful for an error message (or an explanation of _what_ doesn't work, at least)

Comment: @ljacqu: with your code i see blank page for both result(empty result and not empty result) `detect_attack`s not my problem

Comment: @user27133 I [tried the code](http://pastebin.com/UmUGVBeQ) with some substitution for the database fetching (since I don't have your database), but I can assure you it does what it should. My guess is the `if` with `echo` should go outside of the check for `$_GET['userid']` in case I'm missing some kind of context.

Comment: @ljacqu: change Line 4 to : `$ret[] = '';` for empty result. now u see pronlem

Comment: @user27133 Thanks for your time. I wasn't aware of this condition and invite you to check out the updated code in my answer.

Comment: @user27133 Haven't heard back from you. How's it working now?

Comment: @ljacqu: this worked for me :  `$json_output = json_encode($ret);
   if ($json_output != '[""]') { echo $json_output; }` Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo empty($ret) ? '' : json_encode($ret);
```

Hope it helps.